# MKMapKit and points of interest

Tags: ios, mapkit

In the Maps app for iOS, if you tap on a point of interest it displays relevant information about that POI. For example if you tap on the train station icon, it displays the name of the station.

Is it possible to replicate this behaviour using MKMapKit? The icons for the POIs are there on the map, but of course tapping on them does nothing. I've tried reverse geocoding based on where the user tapped, but this just gives me a street address, no data about the POI.

Another strategy I've tried is to use Google Places API, to load POIs within the visible map region, and then setup annotations for each of those POIs. The problem is that this API has a limit of 20 results, so it doesn't work too well in a dense area.

Anyone have any ideas on how I could achieve this?

Comment: How about `MKLocalSearch`? ref. http://nshipster.com/mklocalsearch/

Comment: @KosukeOgawa I did give that a go as well, but unfortunately it requires you to provide some query text, eg. "bus stops", so it's not possible to load all nearby POIs.